# R: Apply function to data frame including only specific rows

Tags: r, function

I have tried to apply a function to a `data.frame` including only specific rows.

My aim is to have a fifth column which includes a function which varies according to the group and `func`. Say I would like to perform a *t*-test in the case that `func=a` and to calculate a mean difference in the case `func=b`. In other words, the first three rows in the fifth column should include the result of a `t.test` (`t.test(n1[1:3],n2[1:3])$p.value`) comparing the `n1` and `n2` in the group `1`. How is this possible?

```
 n1<-c(58,94,58,94,65,87,65,91,20,16)
 n2<-c(37,34,88,23,86,37,80,34,24,67)
 group<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
 func<-c('a','a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a')
 data<-data.frame(n1,n2,group,func)
data
   n1 n2 group func
1  58 37     1    a
2  94 34     1    a
3  58 88     1    a
4  94 23     2    b
5  65 86     2    b
6  87 37     2    b
7  65 80     2    b
8  91 34     3    a
9  20 24     3    a
10 16 67     3    a
```

**EDIT:**

Manually I can do it like this. But is  could I do it if I had +1000 rows with 100+ groups?

```
pvalue1<-t.test(c(58,94,58),c(37,34,88))$p.value
pvalue2<-chisq.test(c(94,65,87,65),c(23,86,37,80))$p.value
pvalue3<-t.test(c(91,20,16),c(34,24,67))$p.value
pvalue<-c(rep(pvalue1,3),rep(pvalue2,4),rep(pvalue3,3))
cbind(data,pvalue)
   n1 n2 group func    pvalue
1  58 37     1    a 0.4737073
2  94 34     1    a 0.4737073
3  58 88     1    a 0.4737073
4  94 23     2    b 0.2381033
5  65 86     2    b 0.2381033
6  87 37     2    b 0.2381033
7  65 80     2    b 0.2381033
8  91 34     3    a 0.9822272
9  20 24     3    a 0.9822272
10 16 67     3    a 0.9822272
```

Comment: Lets say `funcname = "a" ` then `get(funcname)(x)` is the same as `a(x)`

Comment: Your example looks only to run `t.test` within group. Where does *func* come in play?

Comment: @Parfait Yes my aim is to perform within group functions. func=a only tells what I need to perform a different function compared to func=b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the calculations with `dplyr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(p_value = ifelse(func == 'a', t.test(n1, n2)$p.value, chisq.test(n1, n2)$p.value)) 

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
#      n1    n2 group func   p_value
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
#  1   58.   37.    1. a       0.474
#  2   94.   34.    1. a       0.474
#  3   58.   88.    1. a       0.474
#  4   94.   23.    2. b       0.238
#  5   65.   86.    2. b       0.238
#  6   87.   37.    2. b       0.238
#  7   65.   80.    2. b       0.238
#  8   91.   34.    3. a       0.982
#  9   20.   24.    3. a       0.982
# 10   16.   67.    3. a       0.982
```

Comment: Thank! This is what I was looking for. This works also for 1000+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some cool stuff along these lines in Hadley's R4DS book. [Check this out for an example and some discussion around my approach below.](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1)

The following goes some way to achieving what you'd like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

test_function <- function(func, data) {
  if (func == "a") {t.test(data$n1, data$n2)$p.value}
  else if (func == "b") {chisq.test(data$n1, data$n2)$p.value}
}

df %>% 
  group_by(group, func) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(p_value = map2_dbl(func, data, function(x, y) test_function(x, y))) 
  %>% unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's underused `by()` which can split dataframes by one or more factors and then pass subsets into a defined or anonymous function, returning a list of function's output.

**Data** *(assuming functions are strings)*

```
n1 <- c(58,94,58,94,65,87,65,91,20,16)
n2 <- c(37,34,88,23,86,37,80,34,24,67)
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
func < -c('t.test','t.test','t.test','chisq.test','chisq.test',
          'chisq.test','chisq.test','t.test','t.test','t.test')
data <- data.frame(n1,n2,group,func)
```

**By** processing *(using get() to retrieve actual function)*:

```
data_list <- by(data, data$group, function(sub){
  func <- print(as.character(sub$func[[1]]))
  f <- get(func)

  sub$pvalue <- f(sub$n1, sub$n2)$p.value

  return(sub)
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
final_df

#      n1 n2 group       func    pvalue
# 1.1  58 37     1     t.test 0.4737073
# 1.2  94 34     1     t.test 0.4737073
# 1.3  58 88     1     t.test 0.4737073
# 2.4  94 23     2 chisq.test 0.2381033
# 2.5  65 86     2 chisq.test 0.2381033
# 2.6  87 37     2 chisq.test 0.2381033
# 2.7  65 80     2 chisq.test 0.2381033
# 3.8  91 34     3     t.test 0.9822272
# 3.9  20 24     3     t.test 0.9822272
# 3.10 16 67     3     t.test 0.9822272
```